# Dynamic column table in Angular.js + Type scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript, angular2-directives

I want to create the following dynamic column table using Angular.js.

[image]

According to my requirement, column sets such as fruit, vegetables can change dynamically according to the data sets. I want to load data from a JSON file.
ex:

```
[
{
  "clusterID":"1",
  "storeCode": "S2HK",
  "storeName": "store 1",
  "Vegetables":
  {
      "Ordered":"272",
      "Delivery":"250",
      "FR":"70%",
      "Gap":"22"
  },
  "Fruit":
  {
      "Ordered":"300",
      "Delivery":"250",
      "FR":"60%",
      "Gap":"50"
  }
},
{
  "clusterID":"1",
  "storeCode": "SCCC",
  "storeName": "store 2",
  "Vegetables":
  {
      "Ordered":"500",
      "Delivery":"500",
      "FR":"100%",
      "Gap":"0"
  },
  "Fruit":
  {
      "Ordered":"750",
      "Delivery":"700",
      "FR":"90%",
      "Gap":"50"
  }
}
]
```

I tried many ways but was unable to create a dynamic table. How can I create this type of table?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and where you fail if you want someone to be able to reply to your question. Your question is a bit too large and you need to be a bit more specific if you want someone to spend time on an answering you, otherwise, no-one will know where to start really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the table structure like this:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Store</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Store Name</th>
    <th colspan="4">Vegetables</th>
    <th colspan="4">Fruit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Ordered</th>
    <th>Delivery</th>
    <th>FR</th>
    <th>Gap</th>
    <th>Ordered</th>
    <th>Delivery</th>
    <th>FR</th>
    <th>Gap</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>item.storeCode</td>
    <td>item.storeName</td>
    <td>item.Vegetables.Ordered</td>
    <td>item.Vegetables.Delivery</td>
    <td>item.Vegetables.FR</td>
    <td>item.Vegetables.Gap</td>
    <td>item.Fruit.Ordered</td>
    <td>item.Fruit.Delivery</td>
    <td>item.Fruit.FR</td>
    <td>item.Fruit.Gap</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can see the working jsBin [here](https://jsbin.com/dibekanulu/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you @Rohit Sharma. But what will happen when another category (like fruit) will available. According to the above structure we have to change the code.

Comment: Then you need to store the categories in an array and make the dynamic header accordingly.